# Wiznet W5100 unplugged cable detection

Tags: c, embedded, avr, ethernet, lan

How to detect if cable is unplugged on W5100 Ethernet controller?.

In  [datasheet](http://www.wiznet.io/wp-content/uploads/wiznethome/Chip/W5100/Document/W5100_Datasheet_v1.2.7.pdf) I can't find register for cable detection. But chip provides LAN status LED.

Comment: That's a very "high-level" chip, with internal TCP/IP stack. Your best bet is probably to monitor the LED, if you can spare a pin on your processor.

Comment: I thought same thing. But I had Wiznet module so it would be hard to change hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**W5100** does not support reading register to get status if cable is plugged or not (network available or not). You can only check by doing *fake connection* and wait for either any response or timeout.

Instead, you should use **W5200** which has this feature.

Comment: To those coming to this thread late: The newer W5100S also has this feature (detection of cable).